# How to insert data to elastic search from search query

Tags: elasticsearch

I try to copy some data from one elastic db to another elasticsearch db, is there any way to insert data from query results?

Example of results:

```
{
  "took": 29,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
  "total": 572,
  "max_score": 1,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "ref",
      "_type": "dic",
      "_id": "12345",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "name": "Test name"
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

In each db mapping is equals.

Comment: Which data you want to migrate only `_source` ? Did you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I want copy only _source with it's own id, I tried elasticsearchdump, but it's not help me.

Comment: You can write a simple code in any language and push query result to new ElasticDB.

Comment: I found answer, thx

Comment: take a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/modules-snapshots.html

Answer (score 0):

I fork some project witch make a bulk data for elasticsearch, [json-to-es-bulk](https://github.com/velykov/json-to-es-bulk)

I it's compability with 5.6 es version, you can use it in 2 variants:

```
`node index.js -f inputdata.json --index newIndexName --type newIndexType --rewrite true`
```

or

```
`node index.js -f inputdata.json --index --type --rewrite false`
```

after run, you'll see a file request-data.txt, just use it to 
`POST /_bulk`
`[request-data.txt content]`

Input data json file must contains an array of search hits, like this:

`[
   {
      "_index": "oldIndexName",
      "_type": "oldIndexName",
      "_id": "SOME_ID-HiTfm",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
         "orderNumber": "2984",
         "refId": "SOME_VALUE"
      }
   },
   ...
]`